# Automate sending jira ticket content as email

Tags: email, jira

I have jira tickets that Im exploring on how to have as part of workflow (e.g. ticket was closed/resolved), an email is sent with specific ticket content (summary, content, attachments..etc). Is there any free solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The basic documentation for this you will find here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/customizing-email-content-938847640.html